# xcode parse html id data from webview

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

An html file is loaded into webview and that html contains a div like:

```
<div id="test">hello</div>
```

and iOS code as follows. However I receive always an empty value. What I am missing? Thank you

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *body = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                      @"document.getElementById('test').value"];

    NSLog(@"received data: %@", body);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit kludgy, but you can get to the text value (which is a text node and child of the element node you are currently using) by using the following...

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild.data
```

Hope that helps